# Display an alert on the visualforce page from controller

Tags: apex, javascript, action, visual

I have the following code in my visualforce page

```
<div>
   <apex:commandButton id="btnSendI" onclick="something" action="{!Model.displayDoc}"  value="Send " />
   <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="btn" onclick="window.reload(); return false;" />
</div>
```

The action tag calls a method of the controller

```
public PageReference displaySelectedDoc(){
    Controller code....
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,  'Error Message'));
    return 
}
```

What I want here is that instead of the apex page message an alert box would b displayed in the visualforce page. It is a very urgent need. I tried using oncomplete on the button but that is not working either.

Comment: Do you mean a javascript alert?

Comment: yes I wanted a javascript alert

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of ways you can do what you want, probably seeing your code most easy of them is not to use a pagereference method, because this will send you to another url

You could try to declare a string variable and set the error text into it, then at "oncomplete" event, just call a javascript method that consists basically on an alert of your string

Comment: Is there any way I can do it with the page reference method. This is because the button is actually within a popup and the parent page needs to be refreshed once the Send button is clicked. Can't I put the alert within the refreshed page?

Comment: You can do that with js, and I think all the code turns simpler that way, just check"window.opener.location.reload();" method

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish it in below way:

Declare a variable say errorMessage in controller as:

```
public String errorMessage {get;set;}
```

You have to set this variable in apex controller function whenever you need to display error alert.

Non Create a outputpanel in vf page as:

```
<apex:outputpanel id="panelToRefresh" >
<Script> 

var error='{!errorMessage}';
function alertError(){
if(error!='')
alert(error);
}
</Script>
</apex:outputpanel>
```

Now change your button code as:

```
<apex:commandButton id="btnSendI" onclick="something" action="{!Model.displaySelectedDoc}"  value="Send " rerender="panelToRefresh" onComplete="alertError();" />
```

So whenever your controller functions sets errorMessage it will display a javascript alert. Make sure you set errorMessage as blank at first line of your function.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

1. Create a new variable of type String called alertMessage (or any other name).

```
public String alertMessage {get;set;}
```

2. Instead of adding the error message as a PageMessage, set it on the new variable.

```
public PageReference displaySelectedDoc(){
    Controller code....
    alertMessage = 'Error ocurred';
    return null;
}
```

3. On you page, add the following code:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!alertMessage} != ''">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('{!alertMessage');
    </script>
</apex:outputPanel>
```